# (solved) Spring Integration: how to manually control connect/disconnect for a TcpReceivingChannelAdapter in client mode?

Tags: spring, tcp, connection, client, integration

My spring boot kotlin application needs to satisfy these:

- is a TCP client (my app connects to a remote server)
- given remote server sending requests, my app sending responses (when connecting to the given server via e.g. telnet, you instantly see the first incoming messages from the server, before my app is expected to send any response)
- not every request results in a response (hence Spring Gateway approach seems not applicable to me)
- connection control has to take place manually/programmatically (my app must not autostart the connection, my app controls connect/disconnect, e.g. via rest endpoint or so)

This is what I have (simplified):

```
 @Bean
    fun inboundFlow(connectionFactory: AbstractClientConnectionFactory): IntegrationFlow {

        val inbound = TcpReceivingChannelAdapter()
        inbound.isClientMode = true
        inbound.isAutoStartup = false

        inbound.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)

        return IntegrationFlow.from(inbound)

            .channel(requests())

            .get()
    }

    @Bean
    fun outboundFlow(connectionFactory: AbstractClientConnectionFactory): IntegrationFlow {
        val outbound = TcpSendingMessageHandler()
        outbound.isClientMode = true
        outbound.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)

        return IntegrationFlow.from(replies())
            .transform(MyTransformer::toByteArray)
            .handle(outbound)
            .get()
    }

   
    @Bean
    fun connectionFactory(): AbstractClientConnectionFactory =
        Tcp.nioClient(hostname, port)
            .singleUseConnections(false)
            .get()

    @Bean
    fun myFlow(connectionFactory: AbstractClientConnectionFactory,
                   myReceiverService: MyReceiverService): IntegrationFlow? {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(requests())
            .transform(MessageTransformer::transformMyMessage)
            .handle { msg: Message<MyMessage> ->
                myReceiverService.handleMessage(msg)
            }
            .get()
    }
```

Everything works as desired, **except** for the connection control.

Unwanted behaviour with shown code: Spring opens up the connection automatically at start of the spring boot application (resulting in `connection refused` exceptions when the remote server is not listening at that moment). Also I have no means to tell it "connect now".

Wanted and yet missing behaviour:

- spring boot does not connect on startup
- spring boot connects and disconnects only programmatically (e.g. when triggered via rest endpoint)

I made a state diagram showing the workflow I would like to support: [state diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mplNb.png)

Additional comments:
Obviously the `isAutoStartup=false` is not doing what I was hoping. I wonder if this relates to polling, and if there is a way to adjust polling in order to suppress auto connect?

I've also read about the possibility of using spring profiles to achieve connect/disconnect, that was by associating the corresponding connection flows with a profile and then "dynamically activating" the profile. However, every solution that I've seen following this approach also involved restarting the whole spring boot app, which is not only unnecessary delays, but would also (I am assuming here, didn't test it) reset the state of my other services, which is not acceptable for my case. Doesn't exactly look like an elegant solution to me, if I may say so.

Another thing I've read about was the possibility of a control channel, but I couldn't find out how this could work with my example.

Thank you for your suggestions.

---

## Solution:

So we found a solution in the team. Our approach basically follows the idea of adding and removing the connection associated flows:

```
class MyCustomIntegrationFlow(
    private val flowContext: IntegrationFlowContext,
    @Value("\${tcp.client.hostname}") private val hostname: String,
    @Value("\${tcp.client.port}") private val port: Int,
    private val requests: MessageChannel,
    private val replies: MessageChannel
) {

    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    private val inboundFlowId = "inboundFlowId"
    private val outBoundFlowId = "outBoundFlow"
    private val myCustomFlowId = "myCustomFlowId"

    private var started = false

    fun connect() {
        if (!started) {
            started = true

            val connectionFactory = connectionFactory()

            val inboundFlow = inboundFlow(connectionFactory)
            val outBoundFlow = outboundFlow(connectionFactory)
            val myCustomFlow = myCustomFlow()

            logger.info { "Registering inbound flow" }
            flowContext.registration(inboundFlow)
                .id(inboundFlowId)
                .register()

            logger.info { "Registering outbound flow" }
            flowContext.registration(outBoundFlow)
                .id(outBoundFlowId)
                .register()

            logger.info { "Registering Custom flow" }
            flowContext.registration(myCustomFlow)
                .id(myCustomFlowId)
                .register()
        }
    }

    fun disconnect() {
        if (started) {
            logger.info { "Removing Custom flow" }
            flowContext.remove(myCustomFlowId)

            logger.info { "Removing inbound flow" }
            flowContext.remove(inboundFlowId)

            logger.info { "Removing outbound flow" }
            flowContext.remove(outBoundFlowId)

            started = false
        }
    }

    private fun myCustomFlow(): IntegrationFlow {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(requests)
            .transform( /* your transform */)
            .handle {/* handle code */}
            .get()
    }

    private fun inboundFlow(connectionFactory: TcpNioClientConnectionFactorySpec): IntegrationFlow {
        val inbound = Tcp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
            .clientMode(true)

        return IntegrationFlow.from(inbound)
            .channel(requests)
            .get()
    }

    // IMPORTANT: keep the factory defined as "Spec" so Spring connection events work properly
    private fun connectionFactory(): TcpNioClientConnectionFactorySpec =
        Tcp.nioClient(hostname, port)
            .singleUseConnections(false)
            .serializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader(4))
            .deserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader(4))

    private fun outboundFlow(connectionFactory: TcpNioClientConnectionFactorySpec): IntegrationFlow {
        val outbound = Tcp.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
            .clientMode(true)

        return IntegrationFlow.from(replies)
            .transform(/* your transform call */)
            .handle(outbound)
            .get()
    }
}
```

That solved the issue for us.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: added own solution